# EF4 and Code first approach

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to learn about Code First development in EF4 and after googling about it find out that I must download and install some thing named `Entity Framework CTP` and use it to develop a project by code first approach.

But I have a question , is it the only solution to do that(Code first develop)? I mean , I
 **SHOULD** use the CTP ? is there any solution to use tool that already been in Dot Net 4 or VS2010?

any namespace or class exists in dot net 4 to do that?can you just name them for me?
for example after i search i found DataAnnotation namespace. what else that i must use for code first develop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Code First Method is officially part of Entity Framework 4.1. You can download and install it via NuGet (http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework). EF is now at version 4.3 or will be soon atleast.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly not the only [object relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)(ORM) with support for code first development. [Fluent NHibernate](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started)  is another popular code first ORM.

Answer (score 2):

[Entity Framework 4.2 is released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx). As mentioned in link,

> release is just a small update to the DbContext & Code First runtime.
>   The features that were included in EF June 2011 CTP require changes to
>   the Core Entity Framework Libraries that are part of the .NET
>   Framework and will ship at a later date.

You can also read what [Entity Framework June 2011 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx) offers

Comment: DbContext & Code First runtime  are not in EF4?

Comment: They are. But that release slightly differs from june ctp

Comment: thanks . I use the  NuGet Package Manager and install  EF4.3 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In the `Visual Studio 2010` install `NuGet Package Manager`. Now head to `View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console` and console type:

```
install-package entityframework
```

This will install `EntityFramework` in your solution and add the required references to your project.

Now you can write your classes, code and `DbContext` class and start working with code-first EF approach.

More about EF-CF can be found on `Julie Lerman`'s site http://www.learnentityframework.com

Comment: must check Julie's website and try reading her book [Programming Entity Framework Code First] it is very easy read and really good text.